# server could not be accessed from a different network

Tags: java, portforwarding, httpserver, simplehttpserver

I have created a simple http server that sends the client a response in the form of a time stamp. I have performed a port forwarding so the server could be reached through the internet.
I have tested the server using a web browser, using the local host and the ip address and it worked, on several computers.
However when i tried to connect to the server from a computer that is connected to a different network it could not be reached.
What is causing it? how can it be fixed?
Here is my code:

```
public class SimpleServer {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8008), 0);
  server.createContext("/timestamp", new timeHandler());
  server.setExecutor(null);
  server.start();
}

static class timeHandler implements HttpHandler {
public void handle(HttpExchange t){
    if (t.getRequestMethod().contains("GET")){
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
        try {
            String response = ldt.toString;
            t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
            OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
            os.write(response.getBytes());
            os.close();   
        } catch (IOException ex) {System.out.println(ex);}  
    }
 }
}
}
```

Is there any specific configuration in the code that i am missing?
thank you for your help.

Comment: Code looks fine. In particular, it looks like you are allowing connections on any network interface which is a typical problem. I suspect then that the problem lies in your network setup. Add more details about how you are doing the port forwarding. Also indicate if you can verify that your client can reach the machine doing the port forwarding. Then indicate if there is any mention in the logs of the forwarder of a problem.

Comment: I got the IP, gataway and DNS from the cmd-->ipconfig. I have set up the static IP and DNS in the tcp/ip protocol configurations. I logged into the routers port forwarding options and set a range of ports to be forwarded. How can i verify if the client has reached the server? if i see the response in the browser that means he did. is there another way? I haven`t understood your last sentance, what lods?

Comment: Run a ping or a trace route from the client and test if reach the server.

Comment: It sounds like you're on the right track. Try Marco's suggestion. Some router's have built-in web server's to serve an admin interface. Verify that you can open that with your client as one test of connectivity. Some routers keep an audit of what they are doing. That is the log that I was suggesting you look at.